# Updated Excel from apache poi is not giving correct values

Tags: java, json, apache-poi

I am sending a json input to the excel file and updating the excel at specific row, and then reading the updated excel file , but we are not able to read the updated values from excel file

I have noticed that when we open the excel and save manually then i can read the values.if i dont save it manually when i press close button excel save alert is coming even if i dont change anything

1)I am reading the excel with formula and saving it in mongodb and creating the new excel with dynamic Json values,we are able to see the values that are expected but not able to reading the created excel

2)I am giving the excel with json values dynamically iterating them and save the formula with different name ,we are able to see the values that are expected but not able to reading the creating excel

```
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                new File("input excel here"));

        //System.out.println(jsonobject);
        JSONObject rawdatajson = jsonobject.getJSONObject("RawJson");

        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        Sheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Row row1 = sheet.createRow(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Cell cell1 = row1.createCell(i);
            cell1.setCellValue(rawdatajson.get("line_index_" + i).toString());

        }
        workbook.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        evaluator.evaluateAll();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
                ("create excel path here));
        workbook.write(fos);
        fis.close();
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();


        workbook.close();
        System.out.println("Done");
        finaljson = readfinalexcel
                .readcode("created excel path here");
```

I am getting 0.0 when I read the excel but actual value is 15 ,if i save the excel manually and read again the excel then i am getting 15

Comment: Your code writes 100 `String` values in `A3:CV3` of the sheet. Then it tries evaluating formulas. But since the 100 values are text and not numeric, that evaluation might not lead to the expected results. So if the results of `rawdatajson.get("line_index_" + i)` are numbers, you should use `setCellValue(double value)` instead of `setCellValue(java.lang.String value)`.

Comment: The Value of 
"line_index_0":[1,2,3,4,"xxxx",545,"yyyy","9999","str",690,717,"Re","9999",0]